# php_mod and script execution time

Tags: php

I have a script with a long execution time.
Apache is using php_mod.

I start the process in the browser ( open the url ).
I close the browser and the process is still running.

How can I find the apache process and stop it (linux os )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I find the apache process and stop it (linux os )

If you know you ip, find apache process PID:

```
netstat -anp | grep 10.1.1.1 | grep \:80
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            10.1.1.1:48125         ESTABLISHED 7191/apache2
```

And kill it:

```
kill 7191
```

Comment: Are you sure? It's not working...

Comment: It works.Perfect.